# Advantage of EventListenerList over using Vector

Tags: java, swing, vector, eventlistenerlist

what is the advantage of using EventListnerList over Vector ? Which is more preferred ?

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240472/when-to-use-eventlistenerlist-instead-of-a-general-collection-of-listeners

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `Vector` is pseudo "deprecated" in favor of the collections API `List`.
- A `List` may contain whatever you want it to without restriction
- While it would be possible to support multiple different listeners within a `List`, it's management would be complicated, as you'd need to walk the list each time you wanted to find a given type of listener.  You'd be better of using some kind of `Map`, but then, you'd be duplicating what `EventListenerList` does...
- `EventListenerList` will allow you to manage multiple different types of `EventListener`s, but is restricted to managing only class that implement the `EventListener` interface
- Swing components expose `listenerList` which is an instance of `EventListenerList` as a `protected` field, so you don't need to create your own

So, I would suggest, you might use `EventListenerListener` when...

- You're extending from a Swing based component, as it's simpler and is already available...
- Managing multiple different types of listeners
- When your listeners implement `EventListener`

You might consider using a `List` when...

- You only need to deal with a single type of listener and
- You aren't already extending from a Swing based component...as it provides access to the `EventListenerList` any way...